# Hide pages from Google

Tags: google-index

I am working on an application that allows users to create their profiles. As of now all profiles are public and appear in any Search Engine's search results.

We now need to let the user decide if his/her profile would be hidden or visible to various Search Engines. I am unable to figure how can I do this.

I cannot use the robots.txt as it would block all profiles.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Shardul.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @MikeW Say a user creates her profile on my website www.jobsinror.com/rorexpert but would not want it to appear it in Google Search Results as she would like to share it with only selected consultants/recruiters. I need to be able to let her choose to hide her profile from Google.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of hack and assuming that the URL is unique (ignoring QueryString etc), but if the URL is unique you could always do this via a Meta tag

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Then, on your page, an if else statement to either display this (or not).

So, pseudo code would be (within the `<head>` of your HTML page)

```
if (userProfile != "public")
     <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Of course, this only works if the robots obey these rules but I believe Google does!

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this.